Are questions about Mongolian allowed?
Mongolian isn't in the same language family as Mandarin Chinese. It is, however, a language which is spoken as a native language by some citizens of the People's Republic of China, and is even an official language.
Is it ok to ask questions about Mongolian? If so, is it also ok to ask about the Mongolian spoken and written in Mongolia?
For what it's worth, they'll be fairly beginner level questions.

My intuition is that such questions will be marked as off-topic (unless people are so generous), but in the meantime I wonder if the Mongolian community is big enough to have its standalone site. Let's see what the community have to say about this.
